# Difference between a report and a form

Tags: forms, vb6, report

What's the difference between a report and a form?

In VB6, we have Data Report Designer to help with the creation of data reports.

I have not really used a report in my application yet. To me, it looks just like a form, but I think there must be some difference between them, or there is no need for the word "report" to exist?

Would someone please tell me the the difference between a report and a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A form is generally used to add/update/delete records.
A report is a readonly view of the data, you would like to see.

To give you a dumb example, you can assume a test question paper a form & a report card (which shows your grades), a report :)

A real example could be - when you borrow a book from the library, the software will use some sort of form to update the inventory & keep note of who the book is given to. A report in this example, could be - list of all books borrowed in this week.

Does that make it clear as mud?

Comment: Thanks. Now I see the different scenarioes they should apply.

But I'm still unclear about the programatic difference between them. What aspects in programming does a report differentiate from a form so that a report is called specially as a "report" not a "form"?

Comment: Another example: You buy things in a grocery store, they scan it & on screen you see a form which can take in your items, check the actual price from the price setup & store your records in their database. The form gets all the info from the scanner & stores it in DB. What you get is a receipt, which I can say - is a report for you.

Comment: What does a report different from a from in PROGRAMMING?

Comment: Report is a view, it cannot take input from you and store it in DB. It could be a summarized view of things. Think ATM. Your bank transactions can be entered using a form, saved to DB. The printed statement that you get from bank or ATM is the report (i.e it gives you a view of things so that it can be printed.

Comment: Thanks. So do we program quite differently when we code a report?

Comment: Report doesn't require much of programming. Keeping the above example in mind, it needs to know where it will fetch the data from & what needs to be shown on the report alongwith what formatting (tables/borders) etc. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A form is  used to input data whereas a report is generated from the data that has been inputted.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are for data entry - one record at a time.

Reports are for output - all relevant records.

Comment: When we program a report, do we program differently from what we do with form?

Comment: Yes, you have different things to worry about with reports - repeating headers and footers, growable text boxes, alternate line shading, page breaks, etc. However, that's really report 'design' rather than 'programming'.

Comment: Thank you! Both answers are helpful, and it seems only one can be chosen. I'm new here, thank you anyway.

Comment: If two answers are useful, use the up arrows to 'vote them up'. You can vote for answers you don't accept.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I dont have enough reputation to vote it up.